# Query omitting zero-rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
  SELECT 
    [ASACCT].ACCT_MO_I as 'Types'
    ,sum(CASE when [TECH_V].[CLOS_T]='N4'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'N4'
    ,SUM(CASE when [TECH_V].[CLOS_T]='N3'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'N3'
    ,SUM(CASE when [TECH_V].[CLOS_T]='N2'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'N2'
  FROM [supt_oper_anls_dw].[dbo].[TECH_V] as [TECH_V]
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [supt_oper_anls_dw].[dbo].ACCT_DATE_DIM AS [ASACCT]
     ON CONVERT(varchar(10), [ASACCT].GREG_D, 101)
      = CONVERT(varchar(10), [TECH_V].[OPEN_TS], 101)
  WHERE [TECH_INCDT_V].[KGRP_I] ='73fd71ecf84f5080217683869fd819c3'
    and (
          ([ASACCT].ACCT_MO_I > (datepart(MONTH,getdate()))-1-6
       and [ASACCT].ACCT_MO_I <=(datepart(MONTH,getdate()))-1
       and [ASACCT].ACCT_YR_I = (datepart(year,getdate()))
          )
       OR ([ASACCT].ACCT_MO_I > (datepart(MONTH,getdate()))-6-1+12
       and [ASACCT].ACCT_YR_I = (datepart(year,getdate()))-1
          )
        )
    and [TECH_V].Notes like '%MFTFD%'
    and [TECH_V].notes like '%DEV%'
  GROUP BY [ASACCT].ACCT_MO_I,  [ASACCT].ACCT_YR_I
```

not displaying zero rows.
There are some scenarios like in my TECH_V table there couldn't be no data for the where clauses I provided. But I want the output to be displayed as zero.. but instead the entire row is being omitted.

I want output like below

```
1  1  2  3 
2  4  5  6
3  0  0  0
4  2  5  4
5  2  5  6
6  0  0  0
```

but in my actual output, the 3rd and 6th were eliminated.

The code logic is correct.. since it's working properly for other where clauses.

Comment: could you please post the structure of the two tables and some sample data?

Comment: Seems like there is some missing information in this question. For example, why are you using GROUP BY when your query does no aggregation? It would also be helpful to see the schema related to the query and perhaps a little explanation on what problem this query is trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You have to swap your table order:

```
SELECT 
...
FROM [supt_oper_anls_dw].[dbo].ACCT_DATE_DIM AS [ASACCT] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [supt_oper_anls_dw].[dbo].[TECH_V] as [TECH_V]
...
```